# Laravel wrong public path file upload

Tags: file-upload, deployment, path, laravel, laravel-3

I've deployed laravel with this guide.

http://juniorgrossi.com/deploying-laravel-applications-on-a-shared-host/

On my webserver I have a public_html file now containing all my publicly accesable files and a laravel folder containing the rest, so I've split up the default laravel structure for deployment.

On my development server by default the public folder is resting inside the laravel folder instead of being on the same directory level.

The problem I'm getting though is when I use something like this:

```
// Upload the file
Input::upload('image', 'public/uploads', $filename);
```

Same with this.

```
// Upload the file
Input::upload('image', path('public') . 'uploads', $filename);
```

Instead of trying to use the uploads folder that is inside my public_html folder it tries looking for a public file inside my laravel folder now.

And I get a

> Unable to create the "/uploads" directory

Ofcourse on my development server the public folder is still inside the folder so it's logical.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you changed the paths in paths.php?

Comment: I've tried multiple path changes, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind I'm a retarded laravel newbie. I've update my paths.php to ../public_html and it seems to work now. The problem is that I'm using jcrop and I've tried it before with this paths.php setting but I think I've accidentaly tried uploading a .png and thats why it failed with the correct settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the paths.php to ../public_html

I've done this before but it failed since I accidentaly uploaded a png and my jcrop function wich crops and saves images failed because it currently onlt takes jpg. So that left me thinking my paths.php settings were no good while they actually were.

Thanks for helping out though everybody!
(I feel like a fool.)

Answer (score 1):

You may try this (add a slash after the folder name)

```
Input::upload('image', path('public') . 'uploads/', $filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this....just as a test

```
Input::upload('image', URL::to_asset('uploads/'), $filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try
[Intervention/image](http://intervention.olivervogel.net/image) package.
I'm using this and I find it very easy to use. It also has a resize and crop feature.

It's easy as:

```
Image::make(Input::file('file')->getRealPath())->save('uploads/' . $filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the same problem. Then I created it manually, CHMODed the lil' bastard and it worked fine!

Making a long history short (not so long...): just permission!

If you have the permission to Write/Read to the folder, you'll be cool! If you don't, you change the permissions! If you are unable to change it, put the uploaded files where the permissions allows you to access the file.